# Sending notification from service to Interactive desktop

Tags: windows, service, interactive

I'm developing a Windows service and a helper application launched when an user logs in that connects with service using named pipes. If multiple users are logged, multiple instances of the tray icon helper applications are executed.

When a certain event occurs, the service must ask the user to decide an action (like an antivirus asks the user to clean or ignore a virus when found).

In my implementation, based on the current "interactive" session (using `WTSEnumerateSessions`) I send a message to the helper app to display a timed-out dialog box.

I want to know if the approach is correct and to know about better choices.

Comment: It might be preferable to display the dialog box on all sessions simultaneously (or on all sessions where the logged on user is an administrator, depending on context) in case you're running on a server OS.  Windows Server allows multiple interactive sessions simultaneously.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how antivirus/firewall software does. I saw some of them have a timeout period to answer but no idea if they appear in all sessions or only the active one. By the way, interesting point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend using AV/firewall software as a model for how your UI should work.  In my experience, a lot of these products are quite badly designed.